# GnuPlot - plot points in a data file and plot the count of points also

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file `file.dat` arranged in this format:

```
 DataA:
 0 2
 1 3
 7 2
 1 2


 DataB:
 3 2
 6 4
 1 1
```

I want to get 2 plots from this data file.

1. a simple plot of these points.
2. A plot of number of points in each data sets. e.g (DataA has 4 points and DataB has 3 points)

For generating the first plot I am using this

```
set key autotitle columnheader right 
plot for [i=0:1] 'file.dat' using 1:2 index i with lp
```

For the other plot I just want a simple bar chart like this:

[image: plot 2]

Where `y-axis` tells the number of points DataA and DataB have.

I don't understand how to count the points present in the list, simultaneously plotting the data set too.

P.S Can I also get both of the plots side by side?

**EDIT:**
The `file.dat` can contain multiple datas. e.g

```
 DataA:
 0 2
 1 3
 7 2
 1 2

 .
 .
 .


DataZ:
3 2
6 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count points, use `stats`. To plot side by side, use `multiplot`.

```
stats 'file.dat' using 1:2 every :::0::0  name 'A' # to get stats with prefix 'A_'
stats 'file.dat' using 1:2 every :::1::1  name 'B'
set multiplot layout 1,2 # 1 row, 2 columns
plot for [i=0:1] 'file.dat' using 1:2 index i with lp
set object 1 rect from 1,0 to 3,A_records fc rgb 'red'
set object 2 rect from 5,0 to 7,B_records fc rgb 'red'
set xrange [0:8]
max=(A_records>B_records ? A_records:B_records)+0.5
set yrange [0:max]
set format x ''
unset xtics
set xtics ('DataA' 2, 'DataB' 6)
plot -10 notitle
unset multiplot
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNtZZ.png

Comment: what if I dont know how much data I am handling? Like in this case I have `DataA` and `DataB` but I might generate another file that might look like this:

     DataA:
     0 2
     1 3
     7 2
     1 2
    
    
     DataB:
     3 2
     6 4
     1 1
    
    
     DataC:
     0 2
     1 3
     7 2
     1 2
    
    
     DataD:
     3 2
     6 4
     1 1

Comment: Execute `stats` for your file without conditions, number of blocks is in a variable `STATS_blocks`. Then use a loop, look at `do for [...]` construction.